# Как в Python приостановить цикл For до каких либо действий?

Tags: python-3.x, for

Есть список somelist [‘A’, ‘B’, ‘C’, ‘D’, ‘E’]
Пользователю сразу показывается первый элемент somelist[0]

Дальше нужно по циклу показывать элементы списка по нажатию на кнопки. 
Либо следующий, либо предыдущий.
Button1 = ‘Вперед’
Button2 = ‘Назад

Смысл примерно такой:

```
For i in range(len(somelist)):
    if Button1:
        print (somelist[i+1])

    elif Button2:
        print (somelist[??])

    else:
        ...some code…
```

Но тут цикл сразу весь отрабатывается.
Как сделать паузу после каждого IF и ELIF и ждать следующего действия пользователя?

Comment: Но в питоне нет нажатий на кнопки. Может быть, используется какая-то событийно-ориентированная библиотека для работы с GUI?

Comment: tkinter, pyqt, gtk, ... много их. Нужно больше конкретики. А так, конечно возможно -- только нужно больше конкретики :)

Comment: Само собой нет нажатий на кнопки, я и написал, что смысл примерно такой. Пусть будет не кнопка, а любое действие 1 и действие 2. Главное, чтобы цикл после действия 1 показал следующий элемент списка, а после действия 2, предыдущий.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам ***не нужно ходить по списку***, а ***считать позицию элемента в списке***, которая будет изменятся от нажатия на кнопки. Ниже пример возможной реализации. Серьезно относится к этому примеру нельзя, т.к. реализован ради демонстрации

**P.S.** применение `global` переменных - плохая практика, ну и соответственно нажатия кнопок в данном примере просто пример в виде строковых значений

```
elements = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
position = 0


def handle(button):
    global elements, position
    if button == 'Button1' and position > 0:
        position -= 1
    elif button == 'Button2' and position < (len(elements) - 1):
        position += 1
    return elements[position]


print(handle('Button2'))
print(handle('Button2'))
print(handle('Button1'))
```

**Результат** будет такой:

```
B
C
B
```

Comment: Таки работает. Однако хотелось бы без глобальных как то обойтись.

Answer (score 0):

```
somelist = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
i = 0
l = len(somelist) - 1
print(somelist[i])
A

while True:
    fl = input("Вперед(1), Выход(' '), Назад(любое, кроме: 1 или ' '): ")
    if fl=="1":
        i = i+1 if i<l else 0
        pp = somelist[i]
    elif fl!="1" and fl!=" ":
        i = i-1 if i>0 else l
        pp = somelist[i]
    elif fl==" ":
        break
    print(pp)
```

Comment: While довольно медленный цикл.

Comment: Поверте мне на слово, `while` работает гораздо быстрее чем вы нажмете кнопку: "Button1 = `Вперед` Button2 = `Назад` "